# Change port # for mysql on mac

Tags: mysql

I just installed mysql on a mac running 10.6. The mysql version is 5.1.56. I need to have mysql run on port 3307. This article says we can change the port by modifying this file:

```
# vi /etc/my.cnf
```

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/change-default-mysql-port-under-linuxunix/

but there is no such file in /etc. I can see mysql is running ok because I can connect to it just fine, is the way we change the port # different now?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On OSX you can create `/etc/my.cnf` if it does not exist. You can base it on samples found in `/usr/local/mysql/support-files`. Don't forget to restart MySQL for your `my.cnf` to take effect.

Comment: Ok I see the folder /mysql/support-files, which file should I use as a template? I see my-huge.cnf, my-large.cnf, my-medium.cnf, my-small.cnf, etc?

Comment: @user291701: That will depend on your needs. Read the comments at the top of each `my-*.cnf` file and select the one that matches your needs.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like the new installers are adding the port as 3307

To change that follow below steps

```
sudo vi /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
change 3307 from this line <string>--port=3307</string> to 3306
```

Comment: Thank you!  I couldn't figure out why settings in my.cnf had no effect on this.

Comment: I had to add the port line but it worked after a mysql restart. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 4):

On MacOs High Sierra running MySql v8 server, you need the following:

1. Edit `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist`
2. Under `ProgramArguments`, you will see many entries with
   `<string>...</string>` etc,
3. Add the following line: `<string>--port=16000</string>`

Also, to **restart** you need to do the following:

```
launchctl unload -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

and then

```
launchctl load -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Heider, I looked for many answers but only the above helped. Thanks again :)

Comment: You are most welcome SachinKRaj, glad that I could help.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced a similar problem and here's what worked for me. If you installed MySQL using `brew install mysql` then this should work for you.
For context, I'm using macOS Monterey 12, Homebrew 3.4.5, and MySQL 8.0.

MySQL is installed in:
`/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.28_1/`

The configuration file `my.cnf` is located at `/opt/homebrew/etc`.

You can change the default port by specifying a new port in the `my.cnf` file.

First navigate to the homebrew etc folder

```
cd /opt/homebrew/etc
```

Append the new port value to the `my.cnf` file

```
echo "port = 3307" >> my.cnf
```

restart the MySQL service

```
brew services restart mysql
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, the install doesn't create a my.cnf file on Snow Leopard. You can create one yourself under /etc or you can copy one from /usr/local/mysql/support-files/

Then run : 
`sudo cp my-huge.cnf /etc/my.cnf`

Check out the explanation [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,366143,376017#msg-376017)

Comment: I just prefered to copy my-default.cnf and changed what I needed. It works on Yosemite for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a long time to get mysql running on my Mac (OSX 10.11.13) with mysql 5.7.11 to develop wordpress sites on my local machine...

When I used the app duplicator to migrate a website to my local machine I got errors during the database import. This was caused by to stricked sql_mode...

The trick that made it was:

Going to

```
/usr/local/mysql-5.7.11/support-files/
```

and copy the content from `my-default.cnf`

and paste it to

`/etc/my.cnf` (if this file does not exist create it!)

at the very last line of `my.cnf` I added:

```
sql_mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Et voilà: sql_mode is changed permanently!

Whoop whoop!

Answer (score 0):

I installed docker and was having problems with my company wanting to use port 3306 (which is what I was using privately).

Similar problem to you. So this is what I did to fix it.

`sudo vi /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist`

Then you get a long list of script tags and

Insert `<string>--port=3307</string>` into the array. Make sure you put it under the other strings and within the array.

I changed my port to 3307 instead of 3306 and now docker is working.