# How to check MySQL port on Mac

Tags: mysql, macos, port

I have installed MySQL on mac, and was given a default password. Upon starting the server and entering the password, the error below appears:

[image]

How can I check the port mysql is running on?

Comment: I believe you want lsof

Comment: @SteveKline What is iosf? How is it used?

Comment: Please redirect your question to SuperUser.com - this is not a development question

Comment: On MAC create `/etc/my.cnf` if its not there. You can base it on samples found in `/usr/local/mysql/support-files`. Don't forget to restart MySQL for your my.cnf to take effect. Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320424/change-port-for-mysql-on-mac

Comment: @HamzaZafeer I need to locate the port of the server. How do I do that?

Comment: ...this is all I needed: `sudo lsof -i :3306`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an *extremely* stupid dialog box. It is obvious from the text of the error message that the server is running at the correct port. Your problem is the username, the password, or the access level granted to that user.

Comment: How can I change access granted to the user,? ( at present I cannot access the server)

Comment: @Sauron The access granted to the user is defined at the server. If you can't access the server you can't change it.